# How to get Pod logs that is deployed in another server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have two pods installed that are related to a single deployment(replicas=2).
I can easily get the pod logs for server 1 using this command:
microk8s kubectl log pod1.

The problem is that i  want to get the logs of pod2 which is installed on server 2 like this

microk8s kubectl log pod2.
It shows this exception:

```
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log petclinic-app-678589f679-znrxq)
```

The only way to get pod2 logs is to log using ssh to the server2(the second node)  and then execute microk8s kubectl log pod2.

[image]

[image]

On server1 :
[image]

On Server2:
[image]
Is there any way to do that from the masterNode(server1) ?
Thanks.

Comment: If they're in the same cluster, you should be able to use `kubectl logs` from anywhere that can connect to the API server.  If they're not in the same cluster, the Deployment wouldn't be able to create a Pod on the other node.  This seems like a question about how your cluster is set up, though, and not a question about programming _per se_.

Comment: @DavidMaze : let me clarify.I have a cluster (ip address 192.168.198.135 ) say server1.I have joined another node (192.168.198.137) Say Server 2 .In the deployment i mentioned that replicas is 2 so it made 2 pods .One on server1 and the other on server2.My issue how to get logs for the pod installed on server 2.

Comment: @DavidMaze have a look at the attached picture in the post.

Comment: @BenMansourNizar, please provide your deployment file and what microk8s version you're using?